# cx_oracle python issue : ORA-01008: not all variables bound

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, oracle, cx-oracle

i'm trying to insert into my oracle table from python using cx_oracle, but getting below error:
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01008: not all variables bound

```
my input file (test.log) has below content:
123:ABC:676:101:1014
131:BCD:668:110:1103
155:ABE:663:110:1107

conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user='user', password='pwd', dsn='localhost:1521/mydb')
reader = csv.reader(open("C:\\test.log", "r"))
rec = []
curs=conn.cursor()
for line in reader:
    rec.append(line)

curs.executemany("insert into MY_DB.DEPTTABLE values (:0, :1, :2, :3, :4)", rec)
```

Any help is appreciated !

Comment: If rec does not contain a list of 5-tuples (or equivalent sequences) you'll get this error. You'll need to show what the contents of `rec` are.

Answer (score 1):

You can figure it out through use of `pandas.read_csv()` function with `sep= ':'` (or `delimiter=':'`) argument in order to split each rows by colon characters :

```
import pandas as pd
import cx_Oracle
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user='user', password='pwd', dsn='localhost:1521/mydb')
curs=conn.cursor()
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\\test.log',sep= ':',header=None) #to start from the top(first) row 

rec = df.astype(str).values.tolist()

for i in range(len(rec)):
    curs.prepare('INSERT INTO MY_DB.DEPTTABLE VALUES(:0, :1, :2, :3, :4)')
    curs.executemany(None,([rec[i]]))

conn.commit()
conn.close
```

where `rec` is a `list` type parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your reader call, you need to give it the delimiter param:

```
reader = csv.reader(open("C:\\test.log", "r"), delimiter=':')
```

Otherwise, your line variable is just a single string, not a tuple of values.

Comment: Can you please help me on this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64105653/airflow-oracleora-01008-not-all-variables-bound

Comment: @kar, your link leads to nowhere